# Running python scripts on Databricks cluster

Tags: python, pycharm, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-dbx

Is it possible to run arbitrary python script written in Pycharm on my azure Databricks cluster?
Databricks offered using `databricks-connect` but it turned out to be useful for only spark-jobs.
More specifically I'd like to like to use networkx to analyse some graph so huge that my local machine unable to work with them.

I'm not sure if its possible at all...

Thanks in advance!